# getting hold of "value" in k/v pair returned by query

Tags: flask, neo4j

Trying to figure out the right way to parse key-value pairs produced by a Cypher query:

```
@app.route('/about')
    def about():
        data = graph.run("MATCH (n) RETURN n.level")
        for record in data:
    return render_template("output.html",output=record)
```

Please disregard the fact that I'm not combining the returned records into a list prior to populating the template. I do get one record as output, and am ok with that for now.

What I'm struggling with is - how do I handle the resulting k/v pair

**(u'n.level': u'high')**

I mean, if I'm just interested in the value 'high', is there a clean way to get hold of it?

Sorry if this sounds too basic. I do understand, there must be some parsing tools, but at this point, I just don't know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the solution is simple. Flask returns a `py2neo.database.record` object, which can be indexed just like a list, the only caveat being that the list has only one element (not two, as it might appear).
So, if variable `record` above equals to (u'n.level': u'high'), `record[0]` will be equal to `'high'`.
And the `'u'`s can be just ignored altogether, as explained elsewhere on SO.